# How to extract contents of a csv file and place them in a dict file type without using csv module. [python]

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, io

Here is the information in the file:

```
"Part no.","Description","Price"
"453","Sperving_Bearing","9900"
"1342","Panametric_Fan","23400"
"9480","Converter_Exchange","93859"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to open up a file and then store it's contents into a dictionary using the Part no. as the key and the other information as the value. So I want it to look something like this:

```
{Part no.: "Description,Price", 453: "Sperving_Bearing,9900", 1342: "Panametric_Fan,23400",9480: "Converter_Exchange,93859"}
```

I was able to store the text from the file into a list, but I'm not sure how to assign more than one value to a key. I'm trying to do this without importing any modules. I've been using the basic str methods, list methods and dict methods.
Here is my code so far: ( I'm assuming the filename will correctly be entered)

```
textname = input("ENter a file")
thetextfile = open(textname,'r')
print("The file has been successfully opened!")
thetextfile = thetextfile.read()
file_s = thetextfile.split()
holder = []
ck = 0
for c in range(len(file_s)):
   holder.append(file_s[c])
   ck = ck+1
   if(ck == 3):
       holder.insert(c,'\n')
       count = 0
holder_string = "".join(holder)
holder = holder_string.split("\n")
wordlist = {}

#kind of stuck here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SCV is a comma separated variable file so I'm going to assume that each variable is indeed separated by commas:

```
f = open("myfile.csv", 'r')
data = f.read().split('\n') #separates the contents into lines with while leaving out the newline characters
myDict = {}
for x in range(len(data)):
    data[x] = data[x].split(',') #makes each line a list of variables. If the data is contain extra white spaces use the strip() method
    myDict[data[x][0]] = (data[x][1], data[x][2]) #this will make the dictionary like you described in the question
```

don't forget to lose your files (unless you're using the `with` statement).

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to store the values for the dictionary into a tuple instead of having the entire value as one string? I think it would be easier to index it if I wanted to isolate each part.

Comment: OH right. Look by your question, i thought you wanted a string. I edited my question to make it fit what you wanted, but I would suggest that you read and understand the code rather than just copy it. Oh, and I'm really glad it works because I didn't test it XD

Comment: Okay, this works well too. Is there a way to remove the single quotes surrounding each key-value pair?

Comment: I believe the single quotes is being added after split is used. I tried using a for loop to replace each instance of the single quote with an empty character, but it doesn't work.

Comment: By remove the quotes, do you by any chance mean convert them into a integers? Anything you take out of a file is always a string, but you can always change them. You can use the `int()` inbuilt method to convert them into integers.

Comment: The output looks like this: {' "Part no"'.: (' "Description"','"Price" '), ;(' "453": ' "Sperving_Bearing" ',' "9900" '), (' "1342" ': ' "Panametric_Fan" ',' "23400" '),(' "9480" ':' "Converter_Exchange" ',' "93859" ')} each word and number is surronded by single quotes.

Comment: Alright, so I tested out the code, copied and pasted from my answer above, and used the data you gave in the question my the csv file, only I added commas to separate each value, and this is what I got: `{'9480': ('    Converter_Exchange', '  93859'), '1342': ('    Panametric_Fan', '      23400'), '453': ('     Sperving_Bearing', '    9900')}`, so I changed `(data[x][1], data[x][2])` to be `(data[x][1].strip(), data[x][2].strip())` and I got this: `{'9480': ('Converter_Exchange', '93859'), '1342': ('Panametric_Fan', '23400'), '453': ('Sperving_Bearing', '9900')}` which looks correct to me.

Comment: Did you modify the code? Are you using a different file input?

Comment: I'm sorry I posted incorrect information. I updated the way the text is formatted in the csv file in my first post. That's the reason why I keep getting extra quotes around the text.

Comment: Well then, in that case the best thing to do would probably be to take the quotations out of the CSV, but if that's not an option for what ever reason than I would suggest to change `myDict[data[x][0]] = (data[x][1], data[x][2])` to be `myDict[data[x][0][1:-1]] = (data[x][1][1:-1], data[x][2][1:-1])`

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for sticking around and helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```
wordlist = {}
with open(textname, 'r') as thetextfile:
  for line in thetextfile:
    line = line.split()
    wordlist[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

That makes the dict values the (more convenient) list of remaining items. But, if you really wanted the "," string syntax that you have above, maybe:

```
wordlist = {}
with open(textname, 'r') as thetextfile:
  for line in thetextfile:
    line = line.split()
    wordlist[line[0]] = ",".join(line[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
data = {}
with open('input') as f:
    # read headers to make keys for hashes
    headers = re.split(r'\t|\s\s+', f.readline().rstrip())
    # skip the dashes
    f.readline()
    # read the actual data
    for line in f:
         linedata = line.split()
         data[linedata[0]] = { k : v for k, v in zip(headers, linedata) }
# print the parsed data
for part, info in data.items():
    print part
    for k, v in info.items():
        print "\t{} => {}".format(k, v)
```

*Output*:

```
1342
    Part no. => 1342
    Description => Panametric_Fan
    Price => 23400
453
    Part no. => 453
    Description => Sperving_Bearing
    Price => 9900
9480
    Part no. => 9480
    Description => Converter_Exchange
    Price => 93859
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the entire file, and then having to break it apart, it's often easier to process the file line by line. Python makes this very easy.

```
parts = {}

with open(file_name) as fh:
    # Ignore the first two lines. They aren't data.
    next(fh)
    next(fh)

    # Opened files are iterable, line by line.
    for line in fh:
        # Store the separate data elements separately, not munged together.
        i, d, p = line.split()
        parts[i] = {'id': i, 'desc': d, 'price': p}
```